# How to avoid writing full filenames

Tags: shortcuts, filenames

I was wondering whether there is a way in the linux shell to type the first unique part of a filename or dirname and then add "~" or "..." and avoid writing the entire filename.

For example if I have to *cd* to the directory

```
example-program-source-0.11.229-dev
```

Instead of writing

```
cd example-program-source-0.11.229-dev
```

Just to write something like that

```
cd example-program...
```

Or

```
cd example-program~
```

I think there should be something like that integrated in shell, but I don't know what to search for exactly.

Comment: are you asking for the auto-completion in the terminal, or a way in a script?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most shells support what is known as "Tab Completion". Just type the unique part of the filename, and then hit your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. The shell should auto-complete the rest of the filename for you. If there are still multiple files which match what you've typed so far, the shell will either cycle through the matching files as you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or will print a list of all matching files when you double-hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, depending on the configuration. Bash by default prints a list when you tap <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.

Answer (score 5):

You may use `*` as a wildcard:

```
cd example-program*
```

Note that this will expand to *all* the files matching the wildcard. In your case you can only use it if there are only one path starting with `example-program`. If there are multiple directories with the prefix, the command would effectively be expanded to for example:

```
cd example-program-source-0.11.229-dev example-program-other example-program.txt
```

This can be useful if you in fact *want* to work on multiple files, for example if you want to show the contents of all `.log` files in a folder:

```
cat *.log
```

Comment: For the OP's purpose, I use something like `cd example*dev` where I know that this will result in a single match.

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work perfectly, but Darth Android's one is easier. Anyway thanks. +1 from me ;)